# htmx and reachability by google bot

Tags: seo, googlebot

Some days ago I found [htmx](https://htmx.org/) which I really like.

It is simple and gives me a way to use my favorite backend solution, and I can avoid a lot of JavaScript.

But I am unsure if the google bot will find the lazy loaded snippets.

Example:

```
<div hx-post="/clicked"
     hx-trigger="click"
     hx-target="#parent-div"
     hx-swap="outerHTML">
    Click Me!
</div>
```

This tells htmx:

> "When a user clicks on this div, issue an HTTP POST request to
> '/clicked' and use the content from the response to replace the
> element with the id parent-div in the DOM"

Will the google bot find data which I load lazy by htmx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The google crawlers do execute javascript these days, so content lazily loaded by htmx might be visible, but no guarantees.

If you use the `hx-boost` attribute to enhance normal links and forms, that should be very index-bot friendly:

https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-boost/